# Installing Hive and sqoop on Windows (Cygwin)

Tags: cygwin, hive, sqoop

Can someone help me providing the steps to install Hive and Sqoop on Cygwin. I already installed Hadoop-0.20.2 and Hbase latest stable-0.94.1 on Cygwin and working good.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a Hadoop distribution includes both. Inspect the directories containing the Hadoop binaries and see if you discover the bin files. For example, **sqoop** is simply named sqoop and is executable.